# X,Y univariate random variable with $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=G_1(x)G_2(y)$: are they independent?

Tags: random-variable, joint-distribution

Let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be univariate random variables with CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ such that:
$$
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=G_1(x)G_2(y),\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}
$$
where $G_1:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $G_2:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are known functions.

**Question**: Is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are independent RVs?

Can anyone give me some hints?

I tried to:
$$
F_X(x)=\lim_{y\to\infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\lim_{y\to\infty}G_1(x)G_2(y)=G_1(x)\cdot\lim_{y\to\infty}G_2(y)
$$
but I don't know why (or if) $\lim_{y\to\infty}G_2(y)=1$.

Comment: Does the relationship $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=G_1(x)G_2(y)$ hold for _all_ $x$ and $y$ or just at a specific $(x,y)$?

Comment: Also, is $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ the CDF?

Comment: Are you trying to ask whether knowing how to factor the *distribution function* of a *bivariate* random variable $(X,Y)$ into a product of functions of $x$ and $y$ separately suffices to conclude $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit the question now. $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the CDF and the property holds for all $x,y$.

Comment: $\lim_{y\to\infty}G_2(y)=1$ doesn't have to be true.  Consider $H_1(x) = G_1(x) * 0.5$ and $H_2(y) = G_2(y) * 2$ and consider that $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=H_1(x)H_2(y)$ but both $G_1$ and $H_1$ can't have a limit of 1.

Comment: @bsdfish How does the relation between $H1$ and $G1$ affect what the OP is suggesting?

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé If $G_1,G_2$ are known functions, $\lim{y \rightarrow \infty} G_2(y)$ should be defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's true that these assumptions imply $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Simplify the notation by writing $F = F_{X,Y}$.  By definition,

$$F(x,y) = \Pr(X \le x, Y \le y).$$

Therefore the limit of $F(x,y)$ as $y$ increases without bound exists and is the chance that $X$ does not exceed $x$:

$$F_X(x) = \Pr(X \le x) = \lim_{y\to\infty} F(x,y) = G_1(x) \lim_{y\to\infty} G_2(y).$$

Choosing any $x$ for which $F_X(x)\ne 0$ shows $G_2^\infty = \lim_{y\to\infty}G_2(y)$ is nonzero.  (Such an $x$ must exist by the law of total probability, which asserts $\lim_{x\to\infty}F_X(x)=1$.)  Thus

$$G_1(x) = \frac{F_X(x)}{G_2^\infty}$$

for all $x$.  Exchanging the roles of $X$ and $Y$ and using analogous notation,

$$G_2(y) = \frac{F_Y(y)}{G_1^\infty}$$

for all $y$.  Taking the joint limit as both $x$ and $y$ grow without bound shows

$$1 = \lim_{x,y\to\infty} F(x,y) = G_1^\infty G_2^\infty.$$

Therefore

$$F(x,y) = G_1(x)G_2(y) = \frac{F_X(x)F_Y(y)}{G_1^\infty G_2^\infty} = F_X(x)F_Y(y),$$

demonstrating $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: The curious thing is that $G_1(\cdot)$ and $G_2(\cdot)$ both can be be _negative-valued_ functions with, say, $G_1^\infty = -2$ and $G_2^\infty = -\frac 12$ and it will all still work out OK.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: it is not very curious in that, if $(G_1,G_2)$ satisfies the relation, so does $(-G_1,-G_2)$, so you can safely assume both $G_1$ and $G_2$ are positive-valued. Similarly, if $(G_1,G_2)$ satisfies the relation, so does $(\alpha G_1,\alpha^{-1} G_2)$, for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^*$.

Comment: @Xi'an I do understand perfectly well. I just wanted to emphasize (since the OP was wondering how to show that $G_2(y)$ had limiting value $1$ as $y\to\infty$ meaning that he was wanting $G_1=F_X$ and $G_2=F_Y$) that the factorization $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=G_1(x)G_2(y)~\forall~x,y$ implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent without it being necessarily true that $G_1(x) \geq 0, G_2(y) \geq 0$ for all $x, y$; $G_1(x) \leq 0, G_2(y) \leq 0$ for all $x, y$ works just as well.

Comment: @Dilip The $G_i$ could even have complex values if you like :-).

Comment: @whuber That is a can of worms that I prefer not to open....

Comment: @DilipSarwate A side question, if $G_i(x_i) < 0$, then it is my understanding that $G_i(x_i)$ is no longer a valid CDF?  If that is so, then does the concept of probabilistic independence even matter?  I am just curious about this, thanks!

Comment: @KiranK. The question asked is "If a joint CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ can be expressed as $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=G_1(x)G_2(y)~\forall x,y$, then are $X$ and $Y$ independent?" to which the answer is Yes, and it requires a little bit of work to show this. It is _not_ claimed that $G_1(x)$ and $G_2(y)$ are valid CDFs; if you insist on including this claim, the answer is trivially Yes because one of the _definitions_ of independent RV is that the joint CDF factors into the product of the marginal CDFs.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oh OK, I falsely assumed that $G_1(x)$ and $G_2(y)$ were valid CDF's. Thanks!